# Split video file into smaller video files? Android/Java

Tags: java, android, video, split, arrays

> ```
> @Override     
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     if (requestCode == 12345) {
>         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
> ```

```
            Uri videoLocation = data.getData();
            String filePath=Utility.getPath(getApplicationContext(), videoLocation);
            File cur = new File(filePath);
```

My onActivityResult gets the Uri from the gallery. How could I get a function to return a list of 10 second videos.

For example a 36 second video would return 10,10,10, and 6 second videos in a list?

```
private List<File> splitLargeFileIntoSmallerFiles(File cur)
```

I tried File to byte[] and dividing it in 2 to test whether the videos would split but the second one was corrupted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.